# How do you use the math.floor function in this context?

Tags: python-3.x, function, math

I'm very new to coding and I have a coding assignment [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWZEw.png) that I don't quite understand. I know I need to use the math.floor function and I've looked at examples of people using it, but I really don't know how to apply it to this question. Help!

Comment: The question says convert the minutes to hours and days. For example 100000 minutes equals 69 days, 10 hrs and 40 minutes.

Comment: You'd do better to use the floor division operator (`//`) than `math.floor`. There's little point using floating-point for a problem that can be solved entirely with integer arithmetic.